# In luigi what is the difference between the function requires and the @requires mark?

Tags: python, luigi

When specifying tasks some task comes like this

```
class aclass(luigi.Task):
    def requres(self):
        return [anotherTask]
```

others come like

```
@requires(anotherTask)
class aclass(luigi.Task):
    ....something
```

what is the difference and why should one use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining `def requires(self):` you need to return a list of tasks instances, and pass them their parameters. If you have a lot of tasks that have the same parameters it means a lot of boiler plate.

With decorator `@requires` you don't have to re-define the parameters, and you don't have to pass them, `luigi` does it for you.

See https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.util.html